# Prove that $\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+8bc}}<2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

$\sum\limits_{\text{cyc}}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+8bc}}\ge1$ (IMO 2001 problem 2) is mentioned in many books about inequality. However, the upper bound is seldom talked about.

Let *a*, *b* and *c* be positive real numbers. Prove that:

$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+8bc}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+8ca}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+8ab}}<2$$

Or let *a*, *b* and *c* be non-negative real numbers and $ab+bc+ca>0$,

$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+8bc}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+8ca}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+8ab}}\le2$$

The equality holds if one of three is 0.

Firstly I don't think isolated fudging works because it's hard to find a polynomial fraction about *a*, *b* and *c*, e.g. $f=\frac{ka^2+mab+nb^2+\dots}{p(a^2+b^2+c^2)+q(ab+bc+ca)}$, because $f\vert_{a=0}=0$ for all *b* and *c* (we also need $f\vert_{b=0}=0$ for all *c* and *a*, etc) seems impossible.

And I think it's hard to apply AM-GM, because the equality doesn't hold when three radicals are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+8bc}}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}a(b+c)\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{(b+c)(a^2+8bc)}}<2,$$ where the last inequality it's just
$$abc\sum_{sym}(64a^5b+56a^4b^2+24a^4bc-8.5a^3b^3+1014a^3b^2c+925.5a^2b^2c^2)>0,$$ which is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem.** Let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers. Prove that:
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+8bc}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+8ca}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+8ab}}<2.$$

**Proof.** It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+2bc}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+2ca}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+2ab}}<2.$$

Let $x := \frac{2bc}{a^2}, y := \frac{2ca}{b^2}, z := \frac{2ab}{c^2}$. Then $xyz = 8$. We need to prove that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + y}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + z}} < 2.$$

WLOG, assume that $x \le y \le z$.

We split into two cases:

**Case 1.** $x + y \ge 6$

We have $y \ge 3$. Thus,
$$\mathrm{LHS} < 1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 3}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + 3}} = 2.$$

**Case 2.** $x + y < 6$

Using AM-GM, we have
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x}} = \frac{2\sqrt{1 + x}}{2(1 + x)} \le \frac{(1 + x) + 1}{2(1 + x)} = \frac{x + 2}{2 + 2x}$$
and
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + y}} = \frac{2\sqrt{1 + y}}{1 + y} \le \frac{(1 + y) + 1}{2(1 + y)} = \frac{y + 2}{2 + 2y}.$$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{x + 2}{2 + 2x} + \frac{y + 2}{2 + 2y} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + z}} < 2$$
or
$$\frac{x}{2 + 2x}  + \frac{y}{2 + 2y} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + z}}.$$

Using AM-GM, it suffices to prove that
$$ 2\sqrt{\frac{x}{2 + 2x}  \cdot \frac{y}{2 + 2y}} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + z}}$$
or
$$4\cdot \frac{x}{2 + 2x}  \cdot \frac{y}{2 + 2y} > \frac{1}{1 + z}$$
or (using $z = \frac{8}{xy}$)
$$\frac{xy(7 - x - y)}{(1 + x)(1 + y)(xy + 8)} > 0$$
which is true.

We are done.

Comment: If you don't strengthen the inequality, can we also prove it by finally getting case 2 as $xy(511-x-y)>0$?

Comment: @auntyellow Yes. I strengthen it because the stronger one is an old problem.

Comment: How do you think about the common case $\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+dbc}}+\frac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+dca}}+\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+dab}}\le2$ while minimum d is 5/4 (equals when a=b=c)? Michael Rozenberg's C-S approach works but I'm not sure if your approach ($\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + y}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + z}} < 2$ with $xyz=125/64$ ) work.

Comment: @auntyellow I think the approach does not work directly for $d = 5/4$. But I don't know if this approach can be modified to work.